# Extension content script (JS/or CSS) is not applying

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I would like a Google Chrome extension with my own CSS code for website programming. I tried to include my own CSS script with content_scripts, but it didn't work. **I cannot insert css unlike JavaScript**.
Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "XXX",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "file:///*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://www.google.com/*",
            "*://google.com/*"
        ],
        "css": [
            "style.css"
        ],
        "js": [
             "index.js"
        ],
        "all_frames": true
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "style.css"
]
}
```

**style.css**

```
body{
    background-color: #303030;
}
```

**index.js**

```
prompt('code injected');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome lies about the real URL by hiding `www`.
The correct matching pattern is

```
https://www.google.com/*
```

or

```
*://www.google.com/*
```

to match both `http` and `https`.

You can make Chrome display full URLs by right-clicking inside the address bar:

[image]

Comment: If you use Opera, it blocks the search engine by default in its options. For Chrome, open `chrome://policy` and click `show more` for `ExtensionSettings` if it's there, then look for `runtime_blocked_hosts`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but unfortunately it hasn't changed anything. I no longer have to pay attention to whether I am using HTTP or HTTPS, but I cannot insert css UNLIKE JAVASCRIPT. (I changed the question)

Comment: Different sites use different CSS so just overriding `body` may not work.

Comment: This is my side of chrome (sory i'm german): https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wToGzQghRAuGZgfFPqMrO9akLcp6Fn_UKex6XI_Jvv8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There's no ExtensionSettings so policies is not a problem. The problem is that your CSS is overridden by the site as you can see in devtools. There are many ways to increase *specificity*, the easiest is probably to add `!important` e.g. `background-color: #303030 !important;`